# Magento 2.3 - isSaleable returns true when ProductSalableQty is 0

Tags: magento2, inventory

We have many template files (based on the core) that use:

```
if ($_product->isSaleable()):
```

For determining whether or not to show the add to cart buttons. However, we've found if we have 10 of an item and a customer orders 10 (a stock reservation is made making the salable quantity 0) but isSaleable still returns true.

Attempting to add an item to the cart causes an error as this uses the new `IsProductSalableForRequestedQtyInterface`

What is a reliable way (if using MSI) to determine stock levels in phtml? is it not safe to isSaleable anymore or is this an oversight?

Thanks

Comment: Seems to be related to this issue:
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/21218

Answer (score 0):

Since Magento 2.3 you should better call https://www.magentoextensions.org/documentation//interface_magento_1_1_inventory_sales_api_1_1_api_1_1_is_product_salable_interface.html API to check whether a product is salable.

Comment: I'm aware of this, however someone needs to tell the core team that as they're still using isSaleable in template files.